# How can I configure my connector to run in specific worker group in multicluster connect environment in distributed kafka connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

As per the documentation, worker service is set to run before adding connectors. Suppose I am running worker-a with group.id "cluster-a" and worker-b with group.id "cluster-b" on three distributed VM's. What is the configuration that makes connectors to choose their worker group.

Suppose I need to configure debezium mysql connector's tasks to run on cluster-a and jdbc connector's all tasks on cluster-b. How should I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Each Connector group specified by `group.id` communicate with each other over HTTP via their `rest.advertised.listener` (similar to the brokers). Each Connect cluster also requires its own unique config, offsets, and status topics

You'd HTTP POST to one of the group's `rest.port` endpoints, and the tasks will be distributed within that group

However, if you only have 3 machines, there's really no need to setup two unique Connect clusters (JDBC and Debezium tasks can run in the same cluster)